# Bar Button is automatically set in Bottom bar on Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I'm developing an application for iOS with Xamarin , I created a Navigation Controller that has as a Root Table View Controller and from it results in two View Controller, one to display the data listed and another to add new ones . In Table View Controller I add a Button Bar simply by dragging it on the bar and the **operation worked perfectly**.

When i do the same in the ViewController, the Bar Button **automatically sets to the Bottom Bar** in this way:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c35pG.png

Why is this happening? Have you some information about it? Thank you in advance.

This is my StoryBoard:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hahbv.png

Comment: can you share the document outline of your code or story board screen shot, probably you have navigation bar in second view controller at the bottom of screen

Comment: @FahadRehman Storyboard added :)